# Java multiple switch statements - NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, loops, exception, switch-statement

Currently, I am playing around with the switch statement. I run into a problem when I have multiple loops with switch statements.

When I exit the second switch statement (to go one up), Java throws the `java.util.NoSuchElementException`, and I am not quite sure why since the

```
switchOne = sc.nextInt();
```

is supposed to trigger new user input?

I am hoping someone can help me cast some light on this.
I have also tried to use the `scanner` without the `try-with-resources` but it gives the same error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int switchOne = 0;
    int switchTwo = 0;

    boolean breakAdmin = false;

    try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Select one of the options below");
            System.out.println("1: Browse books");
            System.out.println("2: Get a coffe");
            System.out.println("3: See previously checkouts");
            System.out.println("0: Exit");
            System.out.print("Option: ");

            switchOne = sc.nextInt();

            switch(switchOne) {
                case 0:
                    return;
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("!!You choose to browse over books, woohoo!!");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("!!Sit & relax");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("!!Let me get that list for you");
                    break;
                case 99:
                    System.out.println("We welcome you!");

                    try(Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in)) {
                        while(!breakAdmin) {
                            System.out.println("0: exit");
                            System.out.println("1: something");

                            switchTwo = sc2.nextInt();

                            switch(switchTwo) {
                            case 0:
                                breakAdmin = true;
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                System.out.println("!!admin 1");
                                break;
                            default:
                                System.out.println("!!This is the default case");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    breakAdmin = false;
                    break;// case 99 ends
                default:
                    System.out.println("!!This is the default case");
                    break;
            } // switch block ends
        } // while loop ends
    } // try with resources ends
}
```

Comment: What happens if you do `sc.nextLine();` before `switchOne = sc.nextInt();`?

Comment: There is a rule of thumb around streams: "if you didn't open it, don't close it". Since calling `Scanner.close()` will close the wrapped `Readable`, you shouldn't use try-with-resources at all with a `Scanner` wrapping `System.in` (which your code didn't open, the JVM did).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try(Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in)) {`

A try-with-resources construct closes the resources created within the try on exit, so it is calling `sc2.close()` which then closes `System.in`.

After this you try to read from the other `sc`, which tries to read from `System.in`. But since that has been closed it no longer has anything to read.

To fix simply remove the second `try`, the scanner created there does not need to be closed.

EDIT: Another potential issue is that the input stream contains a non-number (for example a newline) which does not get cleared, since it cannot interpret that as a number it will throw the stated exception. When dealing with user input it might be a good idea to just read the whole line `Scanner.readLine()` and transforming the input yourself, such as using `Integer.parseInt(...)`

Comment: Does `System.in` really get closed? Can you refer to some documentation or similar that explains that? Sounds weird in my ears.

Comment: When i removed the second try-with-resources it works... Thought i dont quite understand why. try-with-resources in this example closes System.in?? But its two different system.in objects?

But than how do i close sc2, if i for example for giggles enter the admin menu 99 times than i get 99 objects in memory that wont close?

Comment: @CristianMatthiasAmbæk Thats what the garbage collector is for. The scanner itself does not hold onto any memory and you don't want to close `System.in` if you want to keep reading from it.

Comment: @Gendarme: ["`Scanner.close()`: ... If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's close method will be invoked."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()).

Comment: @Gendarme Or are you referring to the fact that `System.in` can be closed... well, sure it can, it's just a regular `InputStream`.